# Nginx (on docker)return 403 Forbiden when trying to get static files

Tags: django, docker, nginx

**I'm trying to render static and media files using Nginx but i'm always getting 403 forbidden. Some are ssaying that I need to set a USER in nginx.conf file but how ? Need your help.**

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

my nginx.conf file

```
upstream zandu {
    server gunicorn:8000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /app/nginx;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://zandu;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /etc/nginx/staticfiles/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /etc/nginx/media/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not the "correct" approach to remove the `default.conf`.From docs: _[..] By default, this function reads template files in /etc/nginx/templates/*.template and outputs the result of executing envsubst to /etc/nginx/conf.d. [..]_ Read carefully the DockerHub [Nginx page](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)

Comment: I am having the same issue and I can't figure out how to overcome the 403 forbidden. I checked the volume and the files are there, they are just not allowed to be accessed.